# Getting the full result from a Wolfram|Alpha query?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I'm trying to get the list of numbers using this query:

```
WolframAlpha[
  "integers | perfect square and having 9 digits", {{"Result", 1}, "NumberData"}]
```

By default it only returns 10 numbers. How do I get the whole list (something like 23000 entries)?

Comment: You'll be better off working with plain Mathematica code for things like this (where it certainly is possible to do so)

Comment: Replacing `and having 9 digits` with `and greater than 100160064` will return the next 10. Repeat as needed. Or perhaps the paid subscription to WolframAlpha will return more data. I've never seen a sufficiently detailed description of the features to coax me into paying for that.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking the 'More' button on the `WolframAlpha[]` output, then obtain the Number data (see GIF below). The call we get is

```
WolframAlpha["integers | perfect square and having 9 digits", 
  {{"Result", 1}, "NumberData"}, PodStates -> {"Result__More"}]
```

> ```
> {100000000, 100020001, 100040004, 100060009, 100080016, 100100025, 100120036, 
>  100140049, 100160064, 100180081, 100200100, 100220121, 100240144, 100260169, 
>  100280196, 100300225, 100320256, 100340289, 100360324, 100380361}
> ```

We can simulate multiple button clicks. Here's two:

```
Length @ WolframAlpha["integers | perfect square and having 9 digits", 
  {{"Result", 1}, "NumberData"}, PodStates -> {"Result__More", "Result__More"}]
```

> ```
> 20
> ```

Unfortunately there's either a timeout or a memory limit was hit and we can only get up to 9 button clicks:

```
Length@WolframAlpha["integers | perfect square and having 9 digits", 
  {{"Result", 1}, "NumberData"}, PodStates -> ConstantArray["Result__More", 9]]
```

> ```
> 5120
> ```

```
WolframAlpha["integers | perfect square and having 9 digits", 
  {{"Result", 1}, "NumberData"}, PodStates -> ConstantArray["Result__More", 10]]
```

> ```
> Missing["NotAvailable"]
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use *Mathematica*:

```
Select[Table[i, {i, 10^9, 10^10 - 1}], Sqrt[#] \[Element] Integers &]
```

or...

```
Table[j^2, {j, Floor[Sqrt[10^9]], Ceiling[Sqrt[10^10 - 1]]}]
```